# Mail freezes when saving message as draft

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, performance

Ever since upgrading to Mountain Lion, I noticed Mail often freezes up for a good 5-10 seconds at a time in the middle of typing. This happens constantly, and every time I notice it says "Saving Message". Unfortunately, it chooses to do this every time I start typing, and I often stop typing when I don't see the text appearing, so it takes me forever to compose a message of decent length. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this has to do with the draft email being saved to server. As a workaround, try disabling "Store draft messages on the server" in Mail.app Accounts settings.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but that seems to have worked. Thanks! :D